# What is the probability that a group of k people (k =2 is a pair) within a group of size n have logged on to a game at the same time?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Some assumptions:

must have logged on at the same second.

there was a 2 hour window from 10-12(midnight) during which people could have potentially logged on. Lets assume this window was open every day for 3 years.

lets assume on any given day one in 1/5 people (from group of n) played at all and they got on at a uniformly random time from 10-12.

Furthermore, what is the expected number of k sized groups from the total nCr(n, k) groups that have logged on at the same time?

Comment: Against guidelines "do my homework"